# How can I intercept execution of all the methods in a Java application using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming, language-features, aop, interceptor

Is it possible to intercept all the methods called in a application? I'd like to do something with them, and then let them execute. I tried to override this behaviour in `Object.metaClass.invokeMethod`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Is this doable?

Comment: This is probably not a good idea. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Groovy AOP](http://github.com/chanwit/groovy-aop/tree/master)? There's very little [documentation](http://github.com/chanwit/groovy-aop/blob/77f3a17a99d22566ffbcd78e742441b53b5be9e5/userguide/01-Introduction.textile), but it allows you to define pointcuts and advice in a conceptually similar way as for AspectJ. Have a look at the [unit tests](http://github.com/chanwit/groovy-aop/tree/77f3a17a99d22566ffbcd78e742441b53b5be9e5/src/test/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/aop/tests) for some more examples

The example below will match all calls to all woven types and apply the advice before proceeding:

```
// aspect MyAspect
class MyAspect {
  static aspect = {
    //match all calls to all calls to all types in all packages
    def pc = pcall("*.*.*")

    //apply around advice to the matched calls
    around(pc) { ctx ->
      println ctx.args[0]
      println ctx.args.length
      return proceed(ctx.args)
    }
  }
}
// class T
class T {
  def test() {
    println "hello"
  }
}
// Script starts here
weave MyAspect.class
new T().test()
unweave MyAspect.class
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, overriding `Object.metaClass.invokeMethod` doesn't work because when Groovy tries to resolve a method call for a type X, it checks the metaClass of X, but not the metaClass of its parent class(es). For example, the following code will print "method intValue intercepted"

```
Integer.metaClass.invokeMethod = {def name, def args ->
  System.out.println("method $name intercepted")
}

6.intValue()

// Reset the metaClass  
Integer.metaClass = null
```

But this code will not:

```
Object.metaClass.invokeMethod = {def name, def args ->
  System.out.println("method $name intercepted")
}

6.intValue()

// Reset the metaClass  
Object.metaClass = null
```

Your question was "Is it possible to intercept all the methods called in a application?", but could you be a bit more precise about whether you want to:

- Intercept calls to Groovy methods, Java methods, or both
- Intercept calls to only *your* Groovy/Java methods or also intercept calls to Groovy/Java library classes

For example, if you only want to intercept calls to your Groovy classes, you could change your classes to implement [GroovyInterceptable](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyInterceptable.html). This ensures that invokeMethod() is invoked for every method called on those classes. If the nature of the interception (i.e. the stuff you want to do before/after invoking the called method) is the same for all classes, you could define `invokeMethod()` in a separate class and use `@Mixin` to apply it to all your classes.

Alternatively, if you also want to intercept calls to Java classes, you should check out the [DelegatingMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+the+Delegating+Meta+Class).

Comment: I'd like to be able to intercept both Groovy and Java methods calls.

Comment: Then you should use DelegatingMetaClass or a full-blown AOP framework such as groovy-aop or AspectJ

Comment: You can't intercept *all* method calls with a metaClass, because Java methods called from Java wont go through Groovy dispatch. So if you have a Java class calling another Java class, you can't intercept that call without using some sort of AOP or something like that.